# thread synchronization using only shared memory

Tags: multithreading, locking

Recently, I was interviewed at a couple of companies, and was asked the same question:

"You've got N worker threads that can communicate only via shared memory, any other synchronization primitives are not available. The shared memory contains a counter which is initially 0, and each thread must increment it once. Another thread may be added, and there is more space on the shared memory in addition to the counter"

In other words, there are multiple threads, and their access to a shared resource (in this case, a counter, but can be anything else) must be synchronized using shared memory only.

So my solution was as follows:

1. Define 3 more integer variables on the shared memory: REQUEST, GRANTED, FINISHED, and initialize them to -1.
2. Before starting the worker threads, start another manager thread that will coordinate between the worker threads.

Manager thread pseudocode:

```
while (true) {
    if(GRANTED equals FINISHED) {
        GRANTED = REQUEST;
    }
}
```

3. Worker thread pseudocode:

   ```
   incremented = false; 
   while (incremented equals false) {
       REQUEST = this thread ID;
       if(GRANTED equals this thread ID) {
           increment the counter;
           incremented = true;
           FINISHED = this thread ID;
       }
   }
   ```

The question is whether this solution is OK?
Are there other solutions?
Also, this solution is not fair, because a worker may try many times until it gets a chance to actually increment the counter. How to make it fair?

Comment: the question doesnt make much sense ... thats basically multithreaded counting *(which serves no purpose whatsoever)* - and your solution is even more senseless, sorry. Have you left something out?

Comment: There may be variations: e.g., instead of incrementing a counter, each thread prints "Hello <thread ID>", and print calls must be synchronized via shared memory only. I do not agree that the question does not make sense. It makes a lot of sense in the world of high performance computing, where ordinary synchronization primitives are too expensive.

Comment: and even **that** doesnt make any sense - neither is synchronization *"too expensive*" in **any** environment *(you cant get more efficient than with low-level atomics, its simply not possible)* nor is this task relevant for HPC - at all. HPC clusters usually synchronize via queues, memory barriers and sometimes even low-level locks, if applicable. This question is completely out of context and .... senseless - it describes a multithreaded counter, these will **always** be less efficient than single-threaded ones. Also : printing out text is synchronized transparently

Comment: please do not project any qualification test onto reality - you will only make a fool out of yourself because these tests are designed to show your skill at *"thinking outside of the box"*, they literally are out of touch with reality - bascially, they're purely psychological in nature, they have got nothing to do with the world outside of your brain.

Comment: This is not about clusters, imagine a single machine, a high performance application, and lockless synchronization. You contradict yourself: it's either "the question doesnt make much sense" or "these tests are designed to show your skill at thinking outside of the box", it cannot be both

Comment: you're contradicting yourself ... high performance computing is about clusters **by definition**. Also : *"lockless"* synchronization isnt really lockless - thats just a nice way of putting *"performance optimized, low-level spinlocking"* ... just sayian

Comment: OK : `AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true); long i = 0; while(run.get()) i++;`. Thats almost the fastest solution in existence ... one could argue about "atomics vs volatile" but ... its pretty fast and you will have a hard time beating that performance.

Comment: As I wrote in the very beginning, there is only shared memory, no other primitives (including atomic variables) are available

Comment: yet again : that doesnt make any sense, what you just wrote is probably similar to this : *"there is only the color green, no other bose-einstein condensates (including bananas) are available"*.   A single thread does not need synchronization - so you actually could exchange the atomic variable for a `boolean`.

Comment: There are MULTIPLE threads, and their access to a shared resource (e.g. a counter, but can be anything else), must be synchronized  using shared memory only. Your "solution" would make the interviewer dismiss you as a candidate immediately

Comment: synchronization **without** atomicity to **any** extent *(including `volatile`)* is logically, mathematically and technologically  impossible - it is a trick question and if **some**one gets rejected because he/she discovers that ... well ... thats a good thing i guess - one could **approximate** a solution towards pseudo-synchronization but the counter will show illegal values at some point.

Comment: I would like to hear from someone else, who can pinpoint specific problems with the provided solution, or give a better one.

Comment: its not a solution, the counter-change will produce a racing condition - which is unavoidable without atomicity.

Comment: (1) I believe that there's a race where the supervisor may grant the request to a thread that's already finished; (2) to make it fair, the supervisor has to control the requests (although fairness is rather nebulous when each thread only attempts to update once).